# Not able to get value When disable a Div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have designed a page using MVC Razor. In which I had a div such that is following

```
 <div class="row" id="DivDisableForView">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    Product
                </label>
                <br />
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductSeq, Model.products.ToSelectListItems(x => x.ProductName, x => x.Id.ToString(), "", true, "", "Select"), new { @class = "form-control" }).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == true || !Model.IsAdd)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductSeq)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" runat="server">
                <b>Exception Type</b>
                <br />
                @Html.EnumRadioButtonFor(m => m.enumExceptionType, true).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == true || !Model.IsAdd)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.enumExceptionType)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="divTranMode">
                <b>Transaction Mode</b>
                <br />
                @Html.EnumRadioButtonFor(m => m.enumTransactionMode, true).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == true || !Model.IsAdd)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.enumTransactionMode)
            </div>
        </div>

        if (Model.IsAdd)
        {
            <div class="row" id="ViewButton">
                <button id="btnView" name="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    View
                </button>
            </div>
        }
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

If I click the view button,then a grid will load based on the above given field's data and also disabled the fields like following,

```
  $("#DivDisableForView").prop('disabled', true);
```

After that, When I click the submit button, then the disabled field's data is not present, (i.e) The values are null. So how to avoid it or how to disable a div tag without its value get null or empty.Please anybody help

Comment: You can use $("#DivDisableForView").css('display', 'none'); instead of disabling.

Comment: Why you want to disable `div'`?

Comment: Firstly a `<div>` element can't be "disabled"!. If your claiming your values are `null` when you post it has nothing to do with the code you have shown here since you have included a hidden input for each property, so those will post back (as will the selected value of the dropdownlist and the radio button groups if they are not disabled as a result of your `.DisableIf()` code). You need to show the code for the model and the controllers POST method.

Comment: Nothing is disabled here - at least not in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/1fyh3fps/

Comment: Yeah, I tried this way but its not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html elements with `disabled="true"` attribute are not going to be sent over in form data. You can just hide the `div`, and the data will still be sent for processing. Use:

```js
$("#DivDisableForView").hide();
```

**EDIT**

> No, I want to show the fields in the screen

In case you want to keep the fields visible, you could try to set them to `readonly`.

Something like:

```js
$('#DivDisableForView input').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
//maybe also set color to gray
$('#DivDisableForView input').css("background-color", "#eee");
```

Readonly attributes are still going to be sent over in form data.

**EDIT 2**

Solution for select fields:

This JS would solve the select problem:

```js
    $('#DivDisableForView input, #DivDisableForView select').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    //maybe also set color to gray
    $('#DivDisableForView input, #DivDisableForView select').css("background-color", "#eee"); 
    //selects
    $('#DivDisableForView select').attr('onfocus', 'this.defaultIndex=this.selectedIndex;');
    $('#DivDisableForView select').attr('onchange', 'this.selectedIndex=this.defaultIndex');
```

Here is a JSFiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/W4Km8/5340/

Hope it helps.

**EDIT 3**

For radio and checkbox you can do the following:

```js
$('#DivDisableForView :radio, #DivDisableForView :checkbox').click(function()        {
    return false;
});
```

See example (updated JSFiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/W4Km8/5341/

Comment: In that case you could set all fields under the form to 'readonly'.

Comment: Something lile: $('#DivDisableForView input').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

Comment: The readonly fields are going to be sent over in form data. I hope it helps.

Comment: FORM elements with disabled attribute - there is no disabled on other html elements

Comment: Yeah, I tried this and worked, but I can select the data from the dropdown.$('#DivDisableForView input').attr('readonly', 'readonly'); this is not working. @DDan

Comment: Thank you for your responses, Its working only for Dropdown, but I want it for enumRadioButton also. (i.e) It is not working for radio button. See the above given code, In which I had one dropdown and two radio button fields. @DDAN

Comment: Sorry DDan its not working. The radio button is disabled properly, but if I click the radio button after disable, The button is unchecked and The value is passed null or empty.

Comment: By disabled you mean that cannot set the value right? That is the purpose. Doesn't matter if you click it or not. See the fiddle. The first radio button by default is set to checked (by adding checked property) the second and the checkbox to unset. Click event won't change it. I thought that's what you expect.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expect, but here it is not working like that. If I click the second radio button, then the default radio (first radio) button set to unchecked. K anyway, thank you for your valuable time that's given to me. And If you can give a solution for it then please help me. @DDAN

Comment: How to remove the disabled div tag (Solution EDIT 2 )??

Answer (score 1):

Please hide your div instead of disabling.

Use this

```
$("#DivDisableForView").css('display', 'none');
```

**OR**

```
$("#DivDisableForView").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.hide()` or apply using `.css('display','none')` , if you want to disable only, first get the value of the div and store it in a variable then disable the div.

```
var divvalue = $("#DivDisableForView").val();
$("#DivDisableForView").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Actually, I want to post the field's data to my controller, but you are saying that, get the value of the div and store it in a variable.If I do like this, then how can i post the values?